# MS SQL STUFF function with cross reference table

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

On SQL Server 12.0.6024.0, the following query returns ***all*** `CPD_Products` from `dbo.Products` table for each `LC.CustomerName` from `dbo.Customers` table:

```
SELECT distinct TOP (100) PERCENT 
LC.CustomerName, 
STUFF((SELECT '; ' + ILP.ProductId
          FROM dbo.CustomerCrossReferences ICCR, dbo.Products ILP, dbo.Customers ILC 
          WHERE ILP.Product = ICCR.Product and ICCR.Customer = ILC.Customer
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') CPD_Products

FROM dbo.CustomerCrossReferences CCR, dbo.Customers LC, dbo.Products LP
where CCR.Customer = LC.Customer and CCR.Product = LP.Product

GROUP BY LP.ProductId, LC.CustomerName, CCR.Product
ORDER BY 1
```

I would like it to return only those `CPD_Products`, which are related to a customer in `dbo.CustomerCrossReferences`table.
I'm new to this function, not sure how it works with 3 tables. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT LC.CustomerName, LC.Customer,
STUFF((SELECT '; ' + ILP.ProductId
          FROM dbo.CustomerCrossReferences ICCR
          JOIN dbo.Products ILP
            ON ILP.Product = ICCR.Product 
          WHERE ICCR.Customer = LC.Customer   -- correlation to outer query
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') CPD_Products
FROM dbo.Customers LC
GROUP BY LC.CustomerName, LC.Customer;
```

I also used modern JOIN syntax and removed unused joins from main query.

Comment: just changed group by to `GROUP BY LC.CustomerName, LC.Customer` and it worked! thanks!